# Favorite icon is not displayed in IE 9 and 10

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I need to show a favorite icon while loading my html page. No problem with all browsers, except IE in displaying this icon.
my code to display Favorite icon is:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://i.dell.com/images/global/branding/dellecomicon.ico">
<link rel="ICON" href="http://i.dell.com/images/global/branding/dellecomicon.ico">
```

Kindly help me to solve this issues.

Thanks in advance,
Venil

Comment: FWIW, what you have above should work just fine. Where's a page that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @EricLaw: Thanks for your reply. The problem has been solved by following the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, IE has a different code for some reason, put this under your existing code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://i.dell.com/images/global/branding/dellecomicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```